# Tem algum uso real ao implementar métodos não abstratos em uma classe abstrata?

Tags: java, design-pattern, classes-abstratas, método-abstrato

Tem algum uso real ao implementar um método que possua um corpo, (código implementado) em uma classe abstrata que não pode ser instanciada, já que não ocorre erro de compilação?

```
public abstract class ClasseAbstrata {

        //metodo não implementado projetado para ser sobreescrito 
        abstract void metodoAbstrato();

        public void metodoNaoAbstrato(){
            System.out.println("Real impleentação de código em uma classe abstrata");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, totalmente, a maior parte dos métodos que você deseja que uma classe tenha costumam ser implementados, você já sabe o que quer que ele faça.

Provavelmente está pensando ao contrário, e o fato de citar erro de compilação fortalece essa ideia, afinal dar erro de compilação nada tem a ver com esse conceito.

Pense na classe abstrata como uma classe normal que por acaso tem algum método que não deve ter uma implementação. Deixar um método sem implementação deve ser a exceção e não a regra. Na verdade boa parte das classes abstratas nem devem ter um método abstrato.

As pessoas não entendem orientação a objeto. Mesmo assim insistem em usar. OOP não é sobre mecanismos, é sobre conceitos. As pessoas acham que uma classe deve ser abstrata porque tem um método abstrato, mas esse tipo de classe deve existir por uma única e simples razão: essa classe não deve ser instanciada. Esse é o uso correto deste mecanismo, não porque não tem outro jeito de fazer o que quer.

Acontece que se a classe não pode ser instanciada, por acaso permite uma facilidade a mais, algum método pode ficar sem implementação que não causa problema, então pode-se ganhar uma facilidade extra.

Esqueça a ideia que classe abstrata deve ter métodos abstratos, isso é um efeito secundário. Até interfaces hoje em dia já podem ter implementações, e em muitos casos devem ser pensadas para os métodos terem implementações.

Eu devolvo a pergunta: por que quer que um método não tenha implementação? Precisa de um motivo forte para fazer isso.

Você pediu um uso real, mas deu um exemplo não real. O uso real depende de um exemplo real. De qualquer forma o uso real nada tem a ver com o mecanismo de abstração, o uso real depende da sua necessidade e não deve ser dirigido pelo mecanismo. Programação é pegar um problema para resolver, não pegar um mecanismo e tentar enfiar à força na solução para o problema. Por isso as pessoas dão valor exagerado para padrões de projeto, quando deveriam dar valor para conceitos corretos e soluções simples que resolvem um problema real.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Dito tudo isso, um exemplo rápido é o padrão de projeto Template Method.