# Como evitar a repetição de código ao utilizar INTERFACES no JAVA?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface, polimorfismo

Recentemente criando um esqueleto de um sistema de clientes/funcionários (com intuito de aprender e treinar), criei uma interface com dois métodos que obrigam a criação de um setSenha e um autenticador para essa senha. Como havia três subClasses que utilizavam esses dois métodos da interface, era necessário implementar o código nas três, gerando uma repetição de código indesejada.
**INTERFACE**

```
public abstract interface Autenticavel{
    
    public abstract void setSenha(int senha);
        
    public abstract boolean autentica(int senha);
}
```

**CÓDIGO QUE SERIA REPETIDO NAS TRÊS SUBCLASSES**

```
    private int senha;
    
    public void setSenha(int senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public int getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    
    public boolean autentica(int senha)  {
        if (this.senha == senha) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

A solução que encontrei para evitar essa repetição foi criar uma nova classe onde todo o código que seria repetido estaria. Nas subClasses que implementam a interface, fiz com que toda vez que um objeto fosse instanciado, um objeto da classe **Autenticador** também seria criado, e ao invés de repetir o código eu apenas usaria os métodos.
**CLASSE AUTENTICADOR**

```
public class Autenticador {
    
    private int senha;
    
    public void setSenha(int senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public int getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    
    public boolean autentica(int senha)  {
        if (this.senha == senha) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MINHA PERGUNTA**: Há alguma outra forma de evitar essa repetição de código usando interfaces? Dessa maneira que fiz achei um tanto quanto "gambiarra".
ps: Sou iniciante na linguagem JAVA

Comment: Soa um pouco como se você estivesse querendo uma classe abstrata. Pesquise pelo conceito e veja se é o que quer. Tem alguns pontos a melhorar no código, pode usar senha de tipo `String` comparada com `String.equals()` em vez de `==`, e, como `this.senha.equals(senha)` é uma expressão booleana, pode fazer `return this.senha.equals(senha);` em vez de uma lógica `if true return true else return false`.

Comment: Não use interface, use classe abstrata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/366241/112052

Comment: Pode começar Java um pouco mais moderno ou fazer a escolha certa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117134/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/508960/101

Comment: @Maniero Esqueci de sugerir métodos default :) mas no caso, como tem que fazer uma comparação envolvendo estado, e tem também uns getters e setters, não sei se eles podem ser usados.

Comment: @Piovezan Tem que fazer justamente com getter e setter na interface, e a implementação na classe tem que fazer na mão, não tem jeito. Em C# é fácil, em Java não é. Quem quer código curto rescreve em C#. Eu esqueci de sugerir isso :D